# Properties.Settings.Default Doesn't save the values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, settings

I  making  a  wpf  application  but  in  settings  window,  I'm  changing  the  text of textboxes listed in view,  then I click save 
 button to update `Properties.Settings.Default`. Then, I close settings window. I go back to the `MainWindow`. But when I shutdown the application, in the next session my values does not show up. How could I solve it?

Save Button:

```
private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.PC_Name = pcname.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Acc_name = name.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Acc_sname = sname.Text;
        }
```

Loaded Event(Page):

```
private void ayarlarekrani_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pcname.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.PC_Name;
            name.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Acc_name;
            sname.Text= Properties.Settings.Default.Acc_sname;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp